# When and why did Iroh visit the Spirit World?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

Throughout the series, it is hinted that Iroh has visited the Spirit World.  He could see Aang riding Roku's dragon and has a great deal of respect for balance and other Spirits.

My personal theory is that he went there to try to revive or at least speak to his son Lu Ten after he fell at Ba Sing Se, but AFAIK this is simply speculation on my part.  I would, however, like to know if there are any facts that support (or disprove) my theory.

Is there any evidence as to Iroh's motivations for visiting the Spirit World or the time frame in which he did so?

Comment: When did Iroh see Aang while in the Spirit World?

Comment: @NickT - While Iroh was arrested, he saw Aang riding on Roku's Dragon.

Comment: What episode I mean?

Comment: The Winter Solstice, I think.  S1E7 & S1E8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [wiki](http://avatar.wikia.com/) for this series states that:

> ... he was claimed to have journeyed to the Spirit World *in search of his son after death*

Which gives a time during/after the 600 day siege, which began 94 ASC (After Sozins comet). So some time after 95 ASC Iroh travels to the spirit realm, and before 99 ASC (when the avatar awakens).

This is hinted at in [Avatar Extras (Book 2: Earth)](http://nicktoons.nick.com/videos/clip/avatar-extras-zuko-alone-cart-c.html) from the episode *Zuko Alone* (I'll need to rewatch to find out when exactly, and I'll try to hunt down the extras). Bear in mind I picked this up from the wiki so I can't be 100% about the information.

Comment: Interesting.  I wasn't aware there was anything that stated this.  If you can confirm the reference, I'll gladly accept.

Comment: It's on the wiki somewhere I'm sure of it...

Comment: The wiki references Avatar Extras.  Just add the details of what they say in there if you can find it.

Comment: The thing is I can't track down a clip or reference to that.

Comment: I added a link to Avatar Extras.  It is mentioned as a "rumor", but it comes from Nickelodeon.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I keep being redirected to the UK website. Which is probably why I couldn't find it before.

Comment: So... did Iroh manage to talk to his son? :(

Comment: @Omega I don't know. It depends on the hint in the Extrss: Either yes, no, or we don't know.